# Extract a folder and then search for specific file in PHP

Tags: php, path, ftp, zip, extract

I´m building a php programm which uploads a zip file, extracts it and generates a link for a specific file in the extracted folder. Uploading and extracting the folder works fine. Now I´m a bit stuck what to do next. I have to adress the just extracted folder and find the (only) html file that is in it. Then a link to that file has to be generated.

Here is the code I´m using currently:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
if ($zip->open($_FILES['zip_to_upload']['name']) === TRUE) 
{
    $folderName = trim($zip->getNameIndex(0), '/');
    $zip->extractTo(getcwd());
    $zip->close();
} 
else 
{
    echo 'Es gab einen Fehler beim Extrahieren der Datei';
}

$dir = getcwd();
$scandir = scandir($dir);

foreach ($scandir as $key => $value)
{
    if (!in_array($value,array(".",".."))) //filter . and  .. directory on linux-systems
    {
        if (is_dir($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value) && $value == $folderName)
        {
            foreach (glob($value . "/*.html") as $filename) {
                $htmlFiles[] = $filename; //this is for later use
                echo "<a href='". SK_PICS_SRV . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename . "'>" . SK_PICS_SRV . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename . "</a>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So this code seems to be working. I just noticed a rather strange problem. The $zip->getNameIndex[0] function behaves differently depending on the program that created the zip file. When I make a zip file with 7zip all seems to work without a problem. $folderName contains the right name of the main folder which I just extracted. For example "folder 01". But when I zip it with the normal windows zip programm the excat same folder (same structure and same containing files) the $zip->getNameIndex[0] contains the wrong value. For example something like "folder 01/images/" or "folder 01/example.html". So it seems to read the zip file differently/ in a wrong way. Do you guys know where that error comes from or how I can avoid it? This really seems strange to me.

Comment: You have to go to the folder where the files were extracted, read through that to locate the file and generate a link based on that information.

Comment: do you have the possibility to debug through your code, so you can check where something is missing or wrong ?
it seems like $value could be empty. What are the values of $value in each loop ?

Comment: try DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR instead of DS. i was to fast with this, as there is no DS constant of you don't define it for yourself, i apologize

Comment: So it seems to be working! I updated my post to adress the last step.

Comment: you can exctract your uploaded folder in a submfolder with a timestamp or sth. like in its name so you reference to this, or you check the modification date of the folders an select newest (which should be the just uploaded; see [stat-function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stat.php) )

Comment: I found a different approach for the last step. Now everything seems to work just fine. Thank you again for all your help!

Comment: no problem, so your approach seems smoother then my suggestions with the timestamp. I didn't comer over the getNameIndex-function of the zip-class

Comment: so I stumbled upon a rather strange error yesterday. I updated my post. Any help would really be appreciated. Maybe I should post a new question as this problem is a different one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you specify the extract-path by yourself you can try finding your file with php's function "glob"

have a look at the manual:

[Glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)

This function will return the name of the file matching the search pattern.
With your extract-path you now have your link to the file.

```
$dir = "../../suedkurier/werbung/"
$scandir = scandir($dir);
foreach ($scandir as $key => $value)
{
  if (!in_array($value,array(".",".."))) //filter . and  .. directory on linux-systems
  {
     if (is_dir($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value))
     {
         foreach (glob($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value . "/*.html") as $filename) {
           $files[] = $value . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR $filename;
        }
     }
  }
}
```

The matched files will now be saved in the array $files (with the subfolder)
So you get your path like

```
foreach($files as $file){
  echo  $dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. This works if the file is in the general folder "../../suedkurier/werbung/". But in my case the whole extraced folder lies in that path. So it will look something like "../../suedkurier/werbung/folder1/" And I have to search folder1 for the html file. I want to upload many folders, so when there is a folder3 it should find the html of this specific folder. I don´t know the name of the extracted folders beforehand.

Comment: So you can try and combine my answer with the answer of James.
Try using scandir for finding the folders (e.g. folder1, folder2, etc.)(check for directory with is_dir()) which are extracted and then you can use the glob-function in these directories. In this case you have 2 nested foreach-loops

Comment: That sounds good. Unfortunately I´m pretty new to PHP and am struggling with writing the code. Could you post the complete code as an answer here? That would be really helpful.

Comment: I edited my answer, hope this helps you. Note: I have not tested this

Comment: thank you for your answers. I edited my initial post as I still have some problems.

Answer (score 1):

```
$dir = "the/Directory/You/Extracted/To";
$files1 = scandir($dir);
foreach($files1 as $str)
{
    if(strcmp(pathinfo($str, PATHINFO_EXTENSION),"html")===0||strcmp(pathinfo($str, PATHINFO_EXTENSION),"htm")===0)
    {
        echo $str;
    }

}
```

Get an array of each file in the directory, check the extension of each one for htm/html, then echo the name if true.